# Error al acceder a los datos de un DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Tengo un DataTable que se crea dinámicamente según el resultado de un SELECT, la primera vez que se crea no me da ningún problema, pero cuando cambio el SELECT aún recargando la tabla no se puede acceder a los datos de la misma

El error que aparece en la consola del navegador es el siguiente:
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "name", informe is undefined
 file:///C:/Users/jordi.burgos/Downloads/ejemplo minimo/index.js:40
jQuery 8
 file:///C:/Users/jordi.burgos/Downloads/ejemplo minimo/index.js:36
jQuery 2

Encontraréis un ejemplo de este código en https://codepen.io/jordibonarea/pen/OJvNOZB

He creado un código mínimo para poder modelar el ejemplo:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejemplo mínimo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Este es el ejemplo mínimo para que de error el DataTable</h1>
    <select name="prueba_select" id="prueba_select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <table id="table_prueba"></table>
    <div id="item_selected">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#prueba_select').change(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tabla_modal_informes = $('#table_prueba').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                    "position":   "System Architect",
                    "salary":     "$3,120",
                    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                    "office":     "Edinburgh",
                    "extn":       5421
                },
                {
                    "name": "Garrett Winters",
                    "position": "Director",
                    "salary": "5300",
                    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
                    "office": "Edinburgh",
                    "extn": "8422"
                },
                // ...
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "extn" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
            ]
        });
        //cuando hacemos click en sus filas
        $('#table_prueba').on('click','tr',function () {
            //$tabla_modal_informes.rows().deselect();
            // Ontiene datos de la fila seleccionada
            let informe = $tabla_modal_informes.row(this).data();
            $('#item_selected').html('<p>' + informe.name +'</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: viste https://datatables.net/reference/api/pluck()#Examples

Comment: Primero, gracias por responder pero parece que no es lo que busco. El problema está en que cuando cambio el select y se recarga la tabla, no sé por què motivo si selecciono alguna de las filas me parece un error. He colgado el ejemplo reducido, si lo compruebas verás que error aparece.

Comment: Finalmente, alguien me ha dado la sloución. el problema está en el ámbito de la variable $tabla_modal_informes, debe declararse en el exterior de  la función del document.ready() y así ya puede funcionar de manera correcta. Gracias a todos